# Looking for workflow or script for saving Kindle documents

Tags: email, applescript, automator, kindle

I'm using a Kindle DX (3G, no WiFi) for reading documents saved from the web with Readability.  Because Amazon charges a conversion cost for these documents I'm forwarding the documents to my foo.baz@free.kindle.com account.

Amazon then forwards these as emails to me where I use Gmail or Mail.app to click on the link inside each message and laboriously save the corresponding foo.azw download to my Kindle.

I'm wondering if anyone has created an automator workflow or an Applescript that can visit a group of unread Amazon emails and use the links in each to download the corresponding .azw files?

If there's a better way to go about this I'd also be delighted to hear about it.

Comment: To help provide a good answer, what's the purpose behind saving the .azw documents?

Comment: The .azw documents are only saved so I can copy them to the Kindle DX when it's docked via its USB cable.

If Amazon didn't charge per-page conversion costs I could do the whole process via 3G, but the costs quickly add up.

Answer (score 1):

My solution requires you to have an **ifttt** and **Dropbox** accounts :

1. Sign in to **http://ifthisthenthat.com/**
2. create a *Dump Kindle doc* recipe as follow :

   - **Gmail** trigger : *New email from*
     Enter your *foo.baz@free.kindle.com* email adress
   - **Dropbox** action : *Add file from url*
     *File URL* : *{{Body plain}}* (use the *+ Addins* listbox)
     *Dropbox folder path* : whatever...

Then url of the .azw file will be **automatically extracted from the mail** (I tested it because was not clear for me) and corresponding file will be downloaded to your Dropbox folder!

Comment: Update: I'm using a message label GMail trigger for this as the Amazon messages arrive from various customer service addresses.